# JQuery won't pass data labeled sessid when calling drupal service module

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

Hey all I am working on a json call that will implement Drupal's services module with json. I am using jquery's ajax function to call the function but I am getting an error stating that no parameters are being passed. When I look at the query string being posted I notice that sessid is not being passed even though its with the parameters. Below is what Im running.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

    function drupalConnect(src) {
        $.ajax({
            url: src,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                method: 'system.connect'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                return data["result"]["sessid"];
            }
        });
    }

    function getTimestamp() {
        return Math.round((new Date).getTime() / 1000);
    }

    function randString(length) {
        var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var randomstring = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
        }
        return randomstring;
    }


    var session_id = drupalConnect('http://localhost/drupal/services/json-rpc');
    var nonce = randString(10);
    var timestamp = getTimestamp();
    var username = "markusgray";
    var password = "Markus1990";
    var key = '2ae0392e0aebbfeeddefcc962ea1924f';
    var domain = 'localhost';

    var hashObj = new jsSHA(timestamp + ";" + domain + ";" + nonce + ";user.login", "TEXT");
    var hash = hashObj.getHMAC(key, "TEXT", "SHA-256", "HEX");

    var parameters = {
        hash: hash,
        domain_name: domain,
        domain_time_stamp: timestamp,
        nonce: nonce,
        sessid: session_id,
        username: username,
        password: password
    };

    var par = JSON.stringify(parameters);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/drupal/services/json-rpc',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            method: 'user.login',
            params: par
        },
        success: function() {

        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drupalConnect` doesn't return anything, also the return from the `success` callback is just thrown away. The best way to use the data returned from an ajax call is to use it in thee callback itself.

```
function drupalConnect(src){
    $.ajax({
        url: src,
        type: 'POST',
        data:{method:'system.connect'},
        success: function(data){
            var session_id = data["result"]["sessid"]; 
            //use session_id here
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `Asynchronous` ajax, let me elaborate, to get the `session_id` you are making an ajax call. At the moment it will send the request, but it wont ensure that the `session_id` will be assigned at that moment. Hence when you making the second ajax call, the `session_id` may not be assigned for a value.

There are two workarounds for this,

One is, making the first ajax call with an option `async:false` and assign the value within the success call, something like

```
var session_id;

function drupalConnect(src) {
    $.ajax({
        url: src,
        type: 'post',
        async : false,
        data: {
            method: 'system.connect'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            session_id = data["result"]["sessid"];
        }
    });
};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/8TKmq/1/)**

The second one and preferred way is, use of [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), something like

```
$.when(
    // make your first ajax request
).then(function(data) {
    session_id = data["result"]["sessid"];
    // make your second ajax call
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/8TKmq/2/)**